# Looking to use google drive realtime API with google+ hangout application

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api, google-hangouts

I currently have a hangout application and I'd like to add some collaborative functionality to it given the realtime API.

Following the realtime API quickstart guide (adding two text areas and a button to authorize with), I've added the relevant code to the hangout XML module(Is this the correct name for this?)

It looks like, however, whenever I click the "authorize" button from within the google hangout instance, the page might refresh (or something?) and a GET request comes back with a: 400 (Bad Request) response.

Is there something I've overlooked? 
Perhaps, some documentation I missed? 
Is there a better approach to what I'm trying to accomplish?

*EDIT*: More information on the GET request and response from chrome's javascript console:

https://015isqam6kq3vfnd0h572bpk4rvnem82-a-hangout-opensocial.googleusercon…dgets/ifr?fileId=0B2FRfMTFpkH0S3RDUlhDMWNsbjQ&userId=103345858281489162915 400 (Bad Request) 015isqam6kq3vfnd0h572bpk4rvnem82-a-hangout-opensocial.googleusercontent.com…ets/ifr?fileId=0B2FRfMTFpkH0S3RDUlhDMWNsbjQ&userId=103345858281489162915:1

The page (where the hangout content *should* be) then shows:

"Missing or malformed url parameter"

Comment: Can you share more of the response please?

Comment: @AliAfshar Here's the GET response from chrome's console:

 https://015isqam6kq3vfnd0h572bpk4rvnem82-a-hangout-opensocial.googleusercon…dgets/ifr?fileId=0B2FRfMTFpkH0S3RDUlhDMWNsbjQ&userId=103345858281489162915 400 (Bad Request) 015isqam6kq3vfnd0h572bpk4rvnem82-a-hangout-opensocial.googleusercontent.com…ets/ifr?fileId=0B2FRfMTFpkH0S3RDUlhDMWNsbjQ&userId=103345858281489162915:1

The page inevitably shows:
"Missing or malformed url parameter"

Comment: Any more information needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the realtime-client-utils.js that the documentation provides.

The idea with the authorization is that upon authorization, it tries to redirect the page via window.location.href and adds parameters to the end of the URL.

*Removing the redirect, setting the parameters in the parameters object manually, and restarting the authorization process fixes the problem.*